# Is there a way to automate voice calls using Selenium Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Is there a way to automate voice calls using Selenium Java

I have a requirement where , i need to click the call button available in my website and provide the inputs and get the responses based on the input.

Is there any way we can achieve this using selenium

Answer (score 0):

Can you add some additional details to understand the problem.

If you are talking about IVR Testing I don't think you can achieve it using Selenium and Java.

For IVR Testing you can use tools like CYARA or HAMMER, you can find the details in below link.

**https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/ivr-testing-tools/**

If the scenario is upon click call button if you get popup or window opens.

Where you need to provide details, It can be done by switching to popup/window  using switchTo() and send the input using sendKeys(),

If you want to test the output which is a call/voice it can't be done.